# sqlite database not accepting python date into date column

Tags: python, sqlite, date, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to use `datetime.date.today()` to add the current date to the sqlite table column below

```
dateadded = db.Column(db.Date)
```

but sqlalchemy throws the error; `qlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input.`

anyone know why this is happening?

```
@app.route('/creategame', methods=["POST"])
def creategame():
    user=current_user()
    if user:
        new_game = Game()
        new_publisher = Publisher()
        new_developer = Developer()
        new_game.name = request.form.get('gamename')
        new_game.dateadded = datetime.date.today()#datetime.now().date()
        new_game.useradded = current_user()
        new_game.description = request.form.get('description')
        new_game.datepublished = request.form.get('datepublished')
        new_game.publisher = request.form.get('publisher')
        new_publisher.publishername == new_game.publisher
        new_game.developer = request.form.get('developer')
        new_developer.developername == new_game.developer
        print(new_game.name, new_game.dateadded, new_game.useradded, new_game.description, new_game.datepublished, 
        new_game.publisher, new_game.developer) # debug
        if request.form.get('gamename'):
            print(new_game.name, new_game.dateadded, new_game.useradded, new_game.description, new_game.datepublished, 
            new_game.publisher, new_game.developer) # debug
            print("here the second") # debug
            db.session.add(new_developer)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.add(new_publisher)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.add(new_game)
            db.session.commit() #
```

Comment: Hi Kelso
can you please share the code you are using to insert the date into the model?

Comment: sure @IshanJoshi, its 
```
new_game = Game()
new_game.dateadded = datetime.date.today()
db.session.add(new_game)
db.session.commit()
```
(part of a bigger function but i figured id leave that out as it should effect it)

Comment: Please also provide the complete Model you have defined for Game.

Comment: yeah mb i finished the comment too early by accident

Comment: @IshanJoshi added whole function to post

Comment: i did some further testing and found that the same error occured when i replaced the date with `new_game.dateadded = date(2020,10,21)` so im guessing its an issue with the database or how the data is being added to the database, not really sure

Comment: `new_game.dateadded = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Comment: sadly i still get the same error with that @ChrisCharley

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't fix your problem. I've never used `sqlalchemy` so I don't know what it is expecting for dates. As you noted in your other post, [SQLite only has 3 types for storing dates](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). I'll lookup sqlalchemy to see what their docs say.

Comment: Looking at their [DATE](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.DATE) types looks like it should accept the string date I suggested (using `strftime` which produces a text string in the form `2020-10-25`

Comment: yeah seems like something weird is happening, would it help if i linked the repo? @ChrisCharley